# Es posible mostrar mas de una acción con displayMessage de trayicon Java

Tags: java, timer, popup

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, **es posible mostrar mas de un msj en la barra de notificaciones utilizando displayMessage**? Porque e echo un sistema que corre en segundo plano en el SystemTray el cual me arroja un msj con distintas acciones que ocurren en tiempo de ejecución, a veces el sistema puede mostrar mas de un msj junto lo cual no estoy logrando, solo me muestra una acción. Por ej: Necesito mostrar los ticket pendientes de facturar de distintas sucursales lo cual puede a ver mas de una sucursal y en mi barra de notificaciones debe salir un msj que indique esa acción, se entiende? Si imprimo por consola el sistema hace lo que tiene que hacer, muestra todas las sucursales pero en el  **displayMessage** me muestra el msj de una sola. Para ser mas claro pongo mi codigo.

```
ArrayList<String> keyArray = new ArrayList<>();
//    LeerArchivos leer = new LeerArchivos();
    private JFrame parent;
    private PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
    private final Image image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("notificaciones.png")).getImage();
    private final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Notificacion.png", popup);
    //para el Timer
    private Timer timer;
    ///////////////////////////
    SystemTray systemTray;

    public Notificacion() {
    }

    public void instanciarTray() {
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    }

    public void segundoPlano() {
        try {
            if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
                systemTray.add(trayIcon);

                //Se inicia una tarea cuando se minimiza           
                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new miTimerTask(), 1000, segundos());//Se ejecuta cada 5 segundos
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR);
        }
    }

//    Muestra una burbuja con la accion que se realiza
    public void MensajeTrayIcon(String texto, MessageType tipo) {
        trayIcon.displayMessage("Advertencia.", texto, tipo);
    }

    public int segundos() {
        int milisegundos = 0;
        try {
            // Abrimos el archivo con la ruta especificada.
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File("Configuracion de Timer.txt"));
            // Creamos el objeto de entrada
            DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            // Creamos el Buffer de Lectura
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entrada));
            String contenido;
            // Leer el archivo linea por linea
            while ((contenido = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                milisegundos = Integer.valueOf(contenido);
            }
            // Cerramos el archivo
            entrada.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { //Catch de excepciones
            System.err.println("Ocurrio un error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return milisegundos;
    }
```

Class interna **miTimerTask**

```
class miTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        Controlador controlador = new Controlador();

        ArrayList<String> keyArray = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<String> arrayArchivosPnd = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayArchivosNoPnd = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> arrayArchivosPndUnicos = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            buscarAchivos();
        }

        public void buscarAchivos() {
            buscarArchivosPndUnicos(new File("Archivos"));
            leer(arrayArchivosPndUnicos);
        }

        private void buscarArchivosPnd(File ruta) {
//            arrayArchivosPnd.clear();
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
            File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
            if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
                for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                    if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                        buscarArchivosPnd(archivo[i]);
                    } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extension. 
                        if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".pnd")) {
                            arrayArchivosPnd.add(archivo[i].getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void buscarArchivosNoPnd(File ruta) {
//            arrayArchivosNoPnd.clear();
//        Creo el vector que contendra todos los archivos de una ruta especificada.
            File[] archivo = ruta.listFiles();
//        Evaluo si la carpeta especificada contiene archivos.
            if (archivo != null) {
//            Recorro el vector el cual tiene almacenado la ruta del archivo a buscar.
                for (int i = 0; i < archivo.length; i++) {
//                Evaluo si el archivo o la ruta es una carpeta.
                    if (archivo[i].isDirectory()) {
//                    Le paso la nueva ruta de la carpeta si se cambia la ruta e busca nuevamente.
                        buscarArchivosNoPnd(archivo[i]);
                    } else {
//                    Evaluo el tipo de extencion. 
                        if (archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".ana") || archivo[i].getName().endsWith(".cnf")) {
                            arrayArchivosNoPnd.add(archivo[i].getName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void buscarArchivosPndUnicos(File ruta) {
            this.arrayArchivosPndUnicos.clear();
            this.arrayArchivosPnd.clear();
            this.arrayArchivosNoPnd.clear();
            this.buscarArchivosPnd(ruta);
            this.buscarArchivosNoPnd(ruta);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.arrayArchivosPnd.size(); i++) {
                if (!this.existeEnLosNoPnd(this.arrayArchivosPnd.get(i))) {
                    arrayArchivosPndUnicos.add(this.arrayArchivosPnd.get(i));
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean existeEnLosNoPnd(String nombreArchivoPnd) {
            String[] arrayNombreExtensionPnd = nombreArchivoPnd.split(Pattern.quote("."));
//        System.out.println(arrayNombreExtensionPnd[0]);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.arrayArchivosNoPnd.size(); i++) {
                String[] arrayNombreExtensionNoPnd = this.arrayArchivosNoPnd.get(i).split(Pattern.quote("."));
//            System.out.println(arrayNombreExtensionNoPnd[0]);
                if (arrayNombreExtensionPnd[0].trim().equals(arrayNombreExtensionNoPnd[0].trim())) {
//                System.out.println("son iguales");                
                    return true;
                }
            }
//        System.out.println("es un pnd único");        
            return false;
        }

        public void leer(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
            Map<String, String> mapaCodigosArchivo = new HashMap();

            try {
                // Abrimos el archivo con la ruta especificada.
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File("Sucursales.txt"));
                // Creamos el objeto de entrada
                DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                // Creamos el Buffer de Lectura
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entrada));
                String contenido;
                // Leer el archivo linea por linea
                while ((contenido = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] separador = contenido.split(",");
                    mapaCodigosArchivo.put(separador[0], separador[1]);
                }
                keyArray.clear();
                //Recorremos el arrayList
                for (String nombreArchivo : arrayList) {
                    String[] separador = nombreArchivo.split("_");
                    String codSucursal = separador[0].replace("PDA", "").trim();
                    keyArray.add(codSucursal);
//                    System.out.println("array "+keyArray);
                }
                for (String key : mapaCodigosArchivo.keySet()) {
                    int encontrados = this.contarTicketPorSucursal(keyArray, key);
                    if (encontrados > 0) {
                        MensajeTrayIcon("Tienes " + encontrados + " ticket pendiente de la sucursal: " + mapaCodigosArchivo.get(key), MessageType.INFO);
                        System.out.println("Tienes " + encontrados + " ticket pendiente de la sucursal: " + mapaCodigosArchivo.get(key));
                    }
                }
                // Cerramos el archivo
                entrada.close();
            } catch (Exception e) { //Catch de excepciones
                System.err.println("Ocurrio un error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        private int contarTicketPorSucursal(ArrayList<String> keyArray, String key) {
            int contador = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < keyArray.size(); i++) {
                if (keyArray.get(i).equals(key)) {
                    contador++;
                }
            }
            return contador;
        }
    }
```

El resultado es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como dije antes, solo me muestra un solo msj en el popup, alguna idea que estoy haciendo mal? Desde ya agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Creo que te muestra los dos, lo que pasa es que no te da tiempo a ver el primero. Mete un Thread.sleep(1000) dentro de if (encontrados > 0).

Comment: @alopezf1987 **PERFECTO!** Era eso, muchas gracias colega!